# Ensuring that javascript functions execute in the specific order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, datatables

I have a program that is using ajax post methods and dataTables. After fiddling for weeks, I have determined that I simply do not understand how javascript works.
Here is my javascript:

```
$('#SaveTimeSheet').click(function () {
            $("#TimeSheetLoader").removeClass("hidden");
            GetSheetCount();
        });
        function GetSheetCount() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetTimeSheetCount","TimeSheet",null)',
                type: "POST",
                data:{
                    OperatorId: $("#OperatorId option:selected").val()
                },
                success: function (Result) {
                    StartTimeSheet(Result.Result);
                }
            });
        }
        function StartTimeSheet(Result) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "TimeSheet", null)',
                data: {
                    SpecificLocation: $("#SpecificLocation").val(),
                    DetailedPoint: $("#DetailedPoint").val(),
                    SheetStatus: $("#statusSlider").val(),
                    Description: $("#Description").val(),
                    OperatorHours: $("#OperatorHoursSlider").attr("data-value"),
                    OperatorMins: $("#OperatorMinsSlider").attr("data-value"),
                    AssistantHours: $("#AssistantHoursSlider").attr("data-value"),
                    AssistantMins: $("#AssistantMinsSlider").attr("data-value"),
                    OriginalQuote: $('input[name=OriginalQuote]:checked').val(),
                    QuoteNo: $("#QuoteNo").val(),
                    SINumber: $("#SINumber").val(),
                    OperatorId: $("#OperatorId option:selected").val(),
                    SiteName: $("#SiteId option:selected").text(),
                    Code: $("#SiteId option:selected").val() + "-" + $("#OperatorId option:selected").val() + "-" + (Result + 1) + "-" + today
                },
                success: function (Result) {
                    ProcessTable(Result.Result);                      
                },
                error: function (x, e) {
                    if (x.status == 0) {
                        alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
                    } else if (x.status == 404) {
                        alert('Requested URL not found.');
                    } else if (x.status == 500) {
                        alert('Internel Server Error.');
                    } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
                        alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
                    } else if (e == 'timeout') {
                        alert('Request Time out.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function ProcessTable(Result) {
            console.log("Start Table Process");
            var datas = t.rows().data();
            var total = $("#Table tr").length - 1;
            var counter = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                var value = datas[i];
                AddItems(value, Result);
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
            if (counter === total) {
                SendPDF(Result);
            }
        }

        function AddItems(value, Result) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("ProcessTable","TimeSheet",null)',
                    data: {
                        TimeSheetId:Result,
                        BOM_NO: value[0],
                        Stock_Code: value[1],
                        Stock_Description: value[2],
                        Quantity: value[3]
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.Result);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                });
        }
        function SendPDF(Result) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/TimeSheet/SendTimeSheet?Id='+Result,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.Result);
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
```

The trouble I have been having is that the program is executing the SendPDF function in the middle of the ProcessTable function. I have tried to stop this by using a if statement but it still executes.

If you know how to fix my code, great. But if you could explain how javascript executes functions, and in what order. And how to control that order. That would be great.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with JS specifically, since afaik, function calls in JS work the same as in every other language. This sounds more like a sync/async misunderstanding.

Comment: And I don't understand what the issue you're having is. `The trouble I have been having is that the program is executing the Send pdf function in the middle of the ProcessTable function.`. You're calling `SendPDF` from `ProcessTable` though, so I would expect it to run. What's the problem?

Comment: Your problem is the call `AddItems(value, Result);` in your `ProcessTable` function, where the loop will be done before all the `AddItems` calls has.

Answer (score 1):

> But if you could explain how javascript executes functions, and in what order. And how to control that order. That would be great.

JavaScript functions work just like functions in most other languages: When you call a function, it runs to completion and then control returns to where you called it from. (And in most JavaScript environments, you don't even have to worry about multiple threads, because while JavaScript is not a single-threaded language, most environments in which it's used do use just a single thread per global environment, which makes life much simpler.)

The issue in your code is *asynchronicity*. In your code, `SendPDF` is not called in the middle of `ProcessResults`; it's called near the end, after all the calls to `AddItems` have been done and returned. **But**, when you call `AddItems`, all it does is **start** a process (an `ajax` request) that then continues *asynchronously*, separately from the thread running your JavaScript. So `SendPDF` is called **before** all those ajax calls have had a chance to complete.

To fix it, we wait until those ajax calls complete by having `AddItems` return the promise that `$.ajax` gives us:

```
function AddItems(value, Result) {
    // Return the Deferred that $.ajax gives us
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ProcessTable","TimeSheet",null)',
        data: {
            TimeSheetId: Result,
            BOM_NO: value[0],
            Stock_Code: value[1],
            Stock_Description: value[2],
            Quantity: value[3]
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.Result);
        }/*, - Probably don't want this, instead we'll handle
               errors in the calling code
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error");
        }*/
    });
}
```

...and then waiting in `ProcessResults` until all of those promises are resolved (which happens later, after `ProcessResults` has returned):

```
function ProcessTable(Result) {
    console.log("Start Table Process");
    var datas = t.rows().data();
    var total = $("#Table tr").length - 1;
    // Remember the promises from AddItems in an array
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        var value = datas[i];
        promises.push(AddItems(value, Result));
    }
    // Wait until they're all resolved...
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(
        function() {
            // ...and then call SendPDF
            SendPDF(Result);
        },
        function() {
            // At least one of the ajax calls failed, handle it
        }
    );
}
```

`$.when.apply($, someArray)` is the weird-looking notation we need because `$.when` expects a list of promises as a series of arguments instead of as a single array. So we have to use `Function#apply` to spread them out (in ES5 and earlier; in ES2015 and above, we could use spread notation).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Javascript is usually single threaded; it executes a block fully before it jumps to executing another block in its "execution queue".

Now to your code, you are calling SendPDF *inside* ProcessTable and not *after* it. If you want SendPDF to execute after ProcessTable, call it right below the line where ProcessTable is called. The difference is that if you do this, then SendPDF will execute after ProcessTable returns, unlike what is happening with your current code.

The second thing which every Javascript developer needs to be aware of is callbacks pattern that emerges from Javascript being single threaded. Be aware that all those success ajax callbacks will not execute at the same time they are parsed/interpreted! The Javascript engine will immediately continue executing the next line and the callbacks may only execute at some point in the future. If you want to understand this better, put log messages right before those ajax calls as well as inside the success callbacks.

Comment: *"Javascript is always single threaded..."* in most common environments. Not in all environments. (Examples: Nashorn, Rhino.) It's not a language thing, it's an environment thing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Wasn't aware of environments where JS doesn't run single-threaded.